# QT (4) equivalent macros/methods/constants for their Win32 API counterparts?

Tags: winapi, qt, gdi

I am converting some GUI code I originally wrote using the win32 API, to use [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/).

I have come accross some items for which I cant find any direct equivalents. They are:

1. GetRValue
2. GetGValue
3. GetBValue
4. PS_SOLID PS_DASH
5. PS_DOT
6. PS_DASH_DOT
7. PS_NULL
8. MulDiv
9. HBITMAP

Any help?

**[Edit]**

I am building on Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 2):

[QColor](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qcolor.html) class has methods red(), green(), blue().

[BrushStyle](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qt.html#BrushStyle-enum) enum defines different brush patterns.

You can code MulDiv yourself, it just "multiplies two 32-bit values and then divides the 64-bit result by a third 32-bit value"

[QBitmap](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qbitmap.html) is Qt bitmap class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not very concerned about performance, implement MulDiv using 64 bit integers:

```
 long MulDiv(long v1, long v2, long v3)
 {
     return (long)(((long long)v1*(long long)v2) / v3);
 }
```